# The specified Type must be a struct containing no references

Tags: c#, .net, exception, structure, memory-mapped-files

I am attempting to use the `Write<T>` function on the `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` class.  My `T` in this case is as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Message
    {
        public void AddString(string str)
        {
            if (stringContents == null)
                stringContents = new byte[1024 * 10];
            stringContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        }
        public string GetString()
        {
            if (stringContents == null)
                return string.Empty;
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stringContents);
        }
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte[] stringContents;
    }
```

However, when I make a call, such as:

```
//Initialized Elsewhere: MemoryMappedViewAccessor writer
Message messageAlreadyOnWire = new Message();
messageAlreadyOnWire.AddString(data);
writer.Write<Message>(0, ref messageAlreadyOnWire);
```

I receive an error as follows:

> The specified Type must be a struct containing no references.
>   Parameter name: type

The only 'reference' in my struct is a byte array.  Is there any way to resolve this issue?  I'm ok with a fixed-length byte array, but I'm not sure how to declare one without delving into the land of `unsafe`, which I would prefer not to do.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround to this issue, you can use the [MemoryMappedViewStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedViewStream.aspx) instead of the MemoryMappedViewAccessor;  then use conventional stream read/write on it instead of the Accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = Your_Size)]` to `Message.stringContents`.

Comment: The suggested attribute was added to the code.  It still produces the exact same error :(